# syntax error, import os using flask

Tags: python, flask, web

I'm using flask and I keep getting a Internal Server Error when trying to use import os commands, can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? This is the code that I'm using:

```
import os
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return os.environ['REMOTE_ADDR']

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host= '0.0.0.0')
```

Comment: can you provide the full trace back

Answer (score 0):

In your `hello()` function check if `REMOTE_ADDR` is set using `os.environ.get('REMOTE_ADDR')`, so your `hello()` should be as below:

```
def hello():
   if os.environ.get('REMOTE_ADDR'):
      return os.environ['REMOTE_ADDR']
   else:
      return 'Remote address not set'
```

Since, the REMOTE_ADDR isn't set, it would not find the key `REMOTE_ADDR` in the environment variables and will return a `KeyError`.

Your script is supposed to be run as a [CGI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Gateway_Interface) script by a web-server, which sets environment variables like `REMOTE_ADDR`, `REQUEST_METHOD`, etc.

You are running the script by yourself, and these environment variables are not available. That's why you get the `KeyError`.

Hence, the Internal server error.

Comment: I am running on a web server. I have ran the os.environ['REMOTE_ADDR'] on apache and it worked.  is there anything else that could be wrong?

Comment: Does it print out the result if you do `print os.environ['REMOTE_ADDR']` ?